# Unity select a different injection factory

Tags: c#, unity-container

I would like to register two different Injection factories for the same type, for example, it could be the two registrations below.

```
        container.RegisterType<BaseSearchProvider>(
                new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),       
                 new InjectionFactory(c =>ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["Setting 1"]));


        container.RegisterType<BaseSearchProvider>(
            new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["Setting 2"]));
```

For now, foreach type I register manually my constructions. I have different services, but some services need to use the first registration and others the second registration? Is there any way to perform this, by using some "Profile" like this?

```
       container.RegisterType<IMeetingSearchService>("using Setting 1")
```

The only thing I can think off for now as the solution is to inherit the BaseSearchProvider and to register this type so that I can register two different types and adapt all my constructors with this, so I even don't need that selector. But maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to resolve by name.

So you need two different derived types of BaseSearchProvider. Lets call them:

> SettingsOneSearchProvider & SettingsTwoSearchProvider

Now we can get get the right settings by using the 'ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["**settingsname**"]' code in the constructor of the two new providers.

In you registration class you add names to the registrations like this:

```
container.RegisterType<BaseSearchProvider, SettingsOneSearchProvider>("SettingsOne"
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),       
        new InjectionFactory(c =>ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["Setting 1"]));


container.RegisterType<BaseSearchProvider, SettingsTwoSearchProvider>("SettingsOne"
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionFactory(c => ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["Setting 2"]));
```

Now we need an extra resolve method in the registration class to resolve by name:

```
public static T Resolve<T>(string name)
{
    return container.Resolve<T>(name);
}
```

Now you can resolve one of the two by using this code:

```
var provider = RegistationClassName.Resolve<BaseSearchProvider>("SettingsOne");
```

Comment: Thanks... I will test this a bit later... But If I need to derive two classes then , if I understood well,  it is useless, as I can just register those two classes with my injectionfactory  ?

Comment: Injecting a factory into a registration goes against my view of inversion of control. This factory needs to be resolved in the class where you want to use it. That is why we need concrete classes to tell the factory which specific settings we need.